# Database Errors When Recording Membership Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, database

I have an error happening in both my dev and production sites. I have attempted everything I can think of such as clearing the cache, rebuilding the menus, deleted and recreated triggers, upgradded to CiviCRM 4.43, and probably a few other things.

When saving a membership contribution I get this error.

`` $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [ "message" => "DB Error: unknown error" "code" => null "exception" => PEAR_Exception {#2259 #cause: DB_Error {#2265 +error_message_prefix: "" +mode: 16 +level: 1024 +code: -1 +message: "DB Error: unknown error" +userinfo: "INSERT INTO `civicrm_contribution` (`contact_id` , `financial_type_id` , `payment_instrument_id` , `receive_date` , `non_deductible_amount` , `total_amount` , `fee_amount` , `net_amount` , `trxn_id` , `invoice_number` , `currency` , `receipt_date` , `source` , `contribution_status_id` , `check_number` , `campaign_id` , `tax_amount` ) VALUES ( 18203 , 2 , 4 , 20211109145000 , NULL , 200.00 , 0 , 200 , NULL , 'INV_101203' , 'USD' , NULL , 'TEST' , 1 , NULL , NULL , 0 ) [nativecode=1442 ** Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.]" ``

The crux of this is "Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

I am not sure where to go from here. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

The database server is an RDS instance running MySQL.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: It's confusing that it's trying to update civicrm_contact. Can you do `show triggers like 'civicrm_contribution'`?

Comment: @Demerit, I have gotten the system working by taking out the trigger for contributions. The trigger has not changed in about a year but this problem is new. The query is over 2K characters so I can not include it here.  I did upload it to S3: https://onlinesharing18.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/civicrm_contribution_trigger.sql Thanks!